# Need to fix output from Pandas data frame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The program works great but the output is just not in the format i want. As you can se from the output below, the printout for the 'from' and 'to' data is not at the same level as the printout for 'route' and 'date'. How can this be fixed? I want the output from date,route,from and to on the same level.

```
      date    route
  0  05/15/2014  C000001     from     to
  0  278.7  278.6
      date    route
  0  05/15/2014  C000001     from     to
  0  278.6  278.5
```

Also, this program is supposed to iterate through any number of .txt files. But it only works when there is just one text file in the target directory.

```
def array_setter():
    import os
    import glob
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    os.chdir\
    ('/Users/thomaswolff/Documents/Data Exports')
    for file in glob.glob('*.TXT'):
        reader = open(file)
        headerLine = reader.readline()
        mainBody = reader.readlines()
        for col in mainBody:
            valueList = col.split(",")
            data = np.array([valueList])

            arrstr = data[:,[0,1]]
            arrnum = data[:,[5,6]].astype(np.float)

            dstr = pd.DataFrame(arrstr,columns=['date','route'])
            dnum = pd.DataFrame(arrnum,columns=['from','to'])

            routes = dstr['route'] == 'C000001'
            from_ = dnum['from'] > 278.5

            if routes == True:
                if from_ == True:
                    print dstr,dnum
array_setter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with too narrow output and solved it with 
putting (`import pandas as pd` is assumed)

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 130)
```

somewhere in the beginning of the file. Just for completeness I will also mention

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
```

For more options and examples see [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

As for not iterating through *.txt files, can it be that your "for col" loop just needs extra indentation ? That's how it looks to me with your indentations as they are displayed in your post. Your "for file" loop is finished and only then your "for col" loop begins.

By the way, the indentations inside both for-loops are displayed as double indentations, which should not be.

Comment: Well you were certainly correct about the indentation. Funny how such a easy fix can go unnoticed. About the display width, I placed pd.set_option('display_width',130) just below the pandas import and it produced this output: KeyError: 'No such keys(s)'.

Comment: I checked my code and there is nothing more special about it. And the pandas documentation shows the same code (link inserted in the answer). The only crazy idea that I would check: can it be that you copied the command from my post and single quotes were replace by something else (back quotes,for example) ?

Comment: No the quotes are quotes. I even used double-quotes to make sure. I am using the Spyder python IDE and in the pandas options and settings documentation it states: Note that the IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a terminal and hence it is not possible to correctly detect the width. Would this be causing that command to not work?

Comment: I am also using Spyder ... Python console in Spyder, Linux. What console do you use?